# No ejecuta una sentencia con parámetro de sustitución de nombre PDO

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo

Buenas, intento ejecutar una sentencia preparada con parámetros de sustitución de nombre por medio de PDO pero esta no muestra nada, por el lado de la base de datos está correcto pues realizándola de otras formas si que lo muestra.

```
require_once "conexion.php";

$busqueda = "ciudad";
$dato = "Valencia";

try{

$con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pdo WHERE :busqueda = :dato";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);

$result->bindParam(":busqueda",$busqueda, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(":dato", $dato, PDO::PARAM_STR,12);
$result->execute();

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<b>id: </b>" . $row["id"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Nombre: </b>" . $row["nombre"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Ciudad: </b>" . $row["ciudad"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Edad: </b>" . $row["edad"] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
$result->closeCursor();

} catch(Exception $e){
die("<b>Erorr: </b>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br><b>Fila: </b>" . $e->getLine());
}
```

Espero que vosotros encontréis rápido mi error. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Me parece que `bindParam` solo admite valores. Si quieres hacer ese planteamiento creo que debería hacer la verificación por otros medios.

Comment: El caso es que así aparece en la documentación de PHP

Comment: Curioso. Es algo que creo haber leído en alguna ocasión. Por que el script no tiene errores. Y si cambias el campo por un valor fijo da el resultado esperado.

Comment: Si cambio el campo :busqueda por el valor fijo, y comento la linea donde supuestamente sustituye :busqueda, si que funciona y muestra, pero la idea es que pueda seleccionar también el campo

Comment: Correcto. Por eso decía en el primer comentario que igual se debería usar otro método de verificación. ¿Podrías poner el enlace del ejemplo de la documentación donde dice que se puede hacer?

Comment: vaya lo puse abajo!

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que parece no puedo usar esto para sustituir los campos, es decir, el campo del where tengo que ponerlo fijo o por medio de una variable, por lo que parece es para sustituir los valores para realizar la consulta, así si funciona.

```
require_once "conexion.php";

$dato = "Valencia";

try{

$con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pdo WHERE ciudad = :dato";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);

$result->bindParam(":dato", $dato, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<b>id: </b>" . $row["id"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Nombre: </b>" . $row["nombre"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Ciudad: </b>" . $row["ciudad"] . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Edad: </b>" . $row["edad"] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
$result->closeCursor();

} catch(Exception $e){
die("<b>Erorr: </b>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br><b>Fila: </b>" . $e->getLine());
}
```

Comment: El enlace de la documientación es este: http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php pero en los ejemplos es como he mencionado antes, parece que es para sustituir los valores, y no para el campo

Comment: Si fuera para el campo te tocaría concatenarla en la propia consulta (variable $sql) como lo que buscas en tu pregunta.

Comment: Agregaría a la respuesta, que el motivo de esto es porque PDO le envía al motor la consulta a preparar antes de hacer la subtitusión. Esto es para que arme un plan de ejecución por adelantado y pueda usarlo multiples veces (cuando se ejecuta). [Referencia](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990488/5948384)